# Jquery multiply the number generated in the field

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to multiply the annual litres (#save-lt) by the average fuel price (#usd).
The What you save per year in litres is working, any ideas I'm guessing a variable is needed? I'm still learning jquery any help appreciated!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#litres').keyup(function() {
    jQuery('#save-lt').text(parseInt(jQuery('#litres').val()) * 52 / 100 * 12);
  });
  
  jQuery('#usd').keyup(function() {
    jQuery('#save-usd').text(parseInt(jQuery('#save-lt').val()) * ('#usd').val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Enter you fuel consumption per week in litres?</h4>
<input type="text" placeholder="Litres (LT)" id="litres" />

<h4>Enter the average price you pay for a litre of fuel in USD?</h4>
<input type="text" class="fuel" placeholder="USD ($)" id="usd" />

<h2>Annual Savings</h2>

<h4>What you save per year in litres (LT):</h4>
<h3 value="0" id="save-lt">0</h3>
<h3>LT</h3>


<h4>What you save per year in USD ($):</h4>
<h3>$</h3>
<h3 value="0" id="save-usd">0</h3>
```

Comment: Don't use the `keyup` event. use `.on("input", function(ev) {`

Comment: **You have a typo**: `('#usd')` should be `$('#usd')`. Sometimes it helps to open Developer Tools Console and review the errors

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` is better written as `jQuery($ => {` or like `jQuery(function($) {` and than inside you don't need to reuse the `jQuery` name, just the alias `$`

Comment: Try always to use the radix `10` while using `parseInt` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `$` prefix on `('#usd')` and the `#save-usd` element is a `h3` so it doesn't have a `value` to be read using `val()`. Use `text()` for that instead. The extra `)` in the second `keyup` logic should also be removed.

Note that you can alias the `$` variable within the jQuery document.ready handler to avoid needing to use `jQuery` references every and make your code less verbose and easier to read. In addition you can use the `input` event instead of `keyup` to also handle events fired by mouse input, such as copy+paste using context menus. Finally you can omit the `parseInt()` call as the value will be coerced using `Number` when you perform a mathematical operation on it - as you do with the `*` operator.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#litres').on('input', () => $('#save-lt').text($('#litres').val() * 52 / 100 * 12));
  $('#usd').on('input', () => $('#save-usd').text($('#save-lt').text() * $('#usd').val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Enter you fuel consumption per week in litres?</h4>
<input type="text" placeholder="Litres (LT)" id="litres" />

<h4>Enter the average price you pay for a litre of fuel in USD?</h4>
<input type="text" class="fuel" placeholder="USD ($)" id="usd" />

<h2>Annual Savings</h2>

<h4>What you save per year in litres (LT):</h4>
<h3 id="save-lt">0</h3>
<h3>LT</h3>


<h4>What you save per year in USD ($):</h4>
<h3>$</h3>
<h3 id="save-usd">0</h3>
```